# How can I resolve warnings of overlapping spring-boot resources with the maven-shade-plugin?

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven-shade-plugin

I am trying to resolve all warnings that are generated by the maven-shade-plugin. It needs to be able to work with spring-boot, and I have set up the configuration of the plugin to work with it already using transformers.

```
<transformers>
  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
  </transformer>
  <transformer implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                    <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
  </transformer>
  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
  </transformer>
  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer"/>
  <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                    <mainClass>${start-class}</mainClass>
 </transformer>
 </transformers>
```

However, I am getting this warning, and if I try to exclude one of these spring.factories, the resulting uber jar is wrongly configured and the project fails to run correctly. I'm not too familiar with spring configuration, but I'm assuming that these factories get combined and both are needed. Is there a way that I can get rid of this warning without breaking the configuration?

```
[WARNING] spring-boot-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar, spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.2.7.RELEASE.jar define 1 overlapping resources: 
[WARNING]   - META-INF/spring.factories
[WARNING] maven-shade-plugin has detected that some class files are
[WARNING] present in two or more JARs. When this happens, only one
[WARNING] single version of the class is copied to the uber jar.
[WARNING] Usually this is not harmful and you can skip these warnings,
[WARNING] otherwise try to manually exclude artifacts based on
[WARNING] mvn dependency:tree -Ddetail=true and the above output.
[WARNING] See http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/
```